# Как удалить из строки все не числовые значения

Tags: python

Есть строка

```
a = "/1.yuxвапва"
```

как можно оставить в строке только числовые значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки в Python неизменяемы, поэтому нужно создать новую строку.

```
new_a = ''.join([i for i in a if i.isdigit()])
```

Comment: Квадратные скобки не обязательны.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так...

```
a = "/1.yuxвапва"
b = str()
for c in a:
    # isdigit проверяет символ, является ли он цифрой
    if c.isdigit():
        b += c
a = b
```